# Getting Module not found error on terminal

Tags: reactjs, django, webpack, webpack-4, react-error-boundary

I am building a react-django app for which I have created a css folder to add external css to my components and a image folder which has all the images which are required in the components but when I run the app I get this error on my terminal which shows module not found:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/HomePage.js 5:0-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/insta.png' in 'C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\src\components'
resolve './images/insta.png' in 'C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\src\components'
  using description file: C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\package.json (relative path: ./src/components)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\package.json (relative path: ./src/components/images/insta.png)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\src\components\images\insta.png doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\src\components\images\insta.png.js doesn't exist
      .json
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\src\components\images\insta.png.json doesn't exist
      .wasm
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\src\components\images\insta.png.wasm doesn't exist
      as directory
        C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\src\components\images\insta.png doesn't exist
 @ ./src/components/App.js 3:0-34 10:90-98
 @ ./src/index.js 1:0-35

ERROR in ./src/components/css/Homepage.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/components/css/Homepage.css) 5:36-149
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '"C:UsersKuldeep PÞsktopRAMANGymWebsite☼rontendsrc♀omponentspublicSergi2.jpeg"' in 'C:\Users\Kuldeep
P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\src\components\css'
resolve '"C:UsersKuldeep PÞsktopRAMANGymWebsite☼rontendsrc♀omponentspublicSergi2.jpeg"' in 'C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\src\components\css'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\package.json (relative path: ./src/components/css)
    using description file: C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\package.json (relative path: ./src/components/css/"C:UsersKuldeep PÞsktopRAMANGymWebsite☼rontendsrc♀omponentspublicSergi2.jpeg")
      no extension
        C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\src\components\css\"C:UsersKuldeep PÞsktopRAMANGymWebsite☼rontendsrc♀omponentspublicSergi2.jpeg" doesn't exist
      as directory
        C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\src\components\css\"C:UsersKuldeep PÞsktopRAMANGymWebsite☼rontendsrc♀omponentspublicSergi2.jpeg" doesn't exist
    resolve as module
      C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\src\components\css\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\src\components\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\node_modules
        single file module
          using description file: C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/"C:UsersKuldeep PÞsktopRAMANGymWebsite☼rontendsrc♀omponentspublicSergi2.jpeg")
            no extension
              C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\node_modules\"C:UsersKuldeep PÞsktopRAMANGymWebsite☼rontendsrc♀omponentspublicSergi2.jpeg" doesn't exist
        C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\node_modules\"C:UsersKuldeep PÞsktopRAMANGymWebsite☼rontendsrc♀omponentspublicSergi2.jpeg" doesn't exist
      C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\Kuldeep P\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
 @ ./src/components/css/Homepage.css 8:6-108 22:17-24 26:0-78 26:0-78 27:22-29 27:33-47 27:50-64
 @ ./src/components/HomePage.js 4:0-28
 @ ./src/components/App.js 3:0-34 10:90-98
 @ ./src/index.js 1:0-35

webpack 5.68.0 compiled with 2 errors and 1 warning in 9118 ms
```

I have downloaded some loaders like image-webpack-loader, file-loader and url-loader to render these files but I have not configured these loaders in my webpack.config.js file as I don't know the appropriate way to configure it
This is my webpack.confog.js file:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      //additional configuration to handle *.ccs files
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        // This has effect on the react lib size
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

and this my homepage.css file for which I am getting the error :

```
#Homepgbtn1{
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
}
#Homepgbtn2{
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    left: 48.5%;
    right: 50%;
    top: 57%;
    bottom: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
body{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: dimgrey;
    background-image:url('"C:\Users\Kuldeep P\Desktop\RAMAN\GymWebsite\frontend\src\components\public\Sergi2.jpeg"');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here

> C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory

It says that your `node_modules` dir is not in the directory. I don't know much about react but I'm 100% sure that react is searching for `node_modules` dir in `C:\`.
Check your `node_modules` path.

In your react config files you can find the `node_modules` directory or something like that. I don't know anything about react so I can't recommend you any articles or guides. If you don't like that solution you can reinstall `node_modules` file in `C:\` directory.

Comment: I have the node_modules folder in the same directory I mean frontend folder which I have created but I still getting this error

Comment: `C:\node_modules` is the result of traversing up the file tree in search of a `node_modules` directory. Not finding the path is still the issue, but `C:\` is not the configuration that is wrong.